# Dump iCloud keychain in Terminal

Tags: terminal, icloud, security, keychain

I failed to find the path to iCloud keychain to do just `security dump-keychain` - the iCloud keychain isn't shown when I try `security list-keychains`. What is the path to that keychain (or, if it cannot be obtained, how to dump the whole iCloud keychain)?

Or, maybe, Apple Script could help to do that?

Comment: You only need to see it with the Terminal ?

Comment: @Chris, actually, in Single-user mode

Comment: So did you figure out anything?

Comment: It would be interesting if there is a python / api bridge to access all the internal code?  there are some details at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items after looking into the /Library/Keychains file you might lookup how to access "binary" keychain "sqlite" data via python?

Answer (score 9):

iCloud Keychain is stored on disk in a different format than a traditional keychain [ref1](https://gist.github.com/rmondello/b933231b1fcc83a7db0b), [ref2](https://github.com/lifepillar/CSVKeychain). It's located at `~/Library/Keychains/` in a folder named as a long UUID. You can see the modified timestamp change on the contents of that folder as you change something in your iCloud keychain.

Whilst you can use AppleScript and [Usable Keychain Scripting](https://red-sweater.com/blog/170/usable-keychain-scripting) to work with the system and login keychains, there's no way to access the iCloud keychain.

So the only option you're left with is to AppleScript GUI operation of the Keychain Access app.

Comment: The UUID is your system's hardware platform UUID (`IOPlatformUUID`), which you can read using the following shell command ([Ref](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342042/how-can-i-query-the-hardware-uuid-of-a-mac-programmatically-from-a-command-line/342043#342043)): `ioreg -d2 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | awk -F\" "/IOPlatformUUID/{print \$(NF-1)}"`

Comment: Anything changed as of Sep 2023?

Comment: @luckman212 no, IMHO it's unlikely to become less secure in the future.

Answer (score 5):

So I've been trying to figure out something similar for about a year or so - and at this point, I'm willing to say that without super ninja magic it's really not possible to do this using the 'security' command.  I have seen countless questions without an answer.

Although there is no actual confirmation its impossible there seems to be a preponderance of evidence suggesting it is not possible.