# How can I query the hardware UUID of a Mac programmatically from a command line?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, uuid

The hardware universally unique identifier (UUID) can often be used by developers to associate information unique to a Mac. This identifier will usually persist through OS upgrades or reinstalls, as well as across multiple OSes in multi-boot installations. I would like to be able to retrieve the UUID via a command line in macOS in order to use with a script.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `ioreg` command can be used for this task.

```
ioreg -d2 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | awk -F\" '/IOPlatformUUID/{print $(NF-1)}'
```

Similarly, you can get the same information in a Property List (plist/xml) format by including the `-a` option which is useful for implementations that work with XML better. One command line example would be to use `xmllint --xpath`

```
ioreg -ad2 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | 
  xmllint --xpath '//key[.="IOPlatformUUID"]/following-sibling::*[1]/text()' -
```

As of macOS Monterey 12, the `plutil` command can also be used to extract this value.

```
ioreg -ad2 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | 
  plutil -extract IORegistryEntryChildren.0.IOPlatformUUID raw -
```

I often see the `system_profiler` command used for this task, however, I have found the `ioreg` method to be slightly faster if performance is a concern.

```
time system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/UUID/ { print $NF }'

real    0m0.295s
user    0m0.110s
sys     0m0.074s


time ioreg -d2 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | awk -F\" '/IOPlatformUUID/{print $(NF-1)}'

real    0m0.029s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.004s
```